# How to add group layers/TOC to ArcGIS web map/web application?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, table-of-contents, group-layer

I am new to arcgis online and am trying to create a web map that has some kind of grouped layers. I have tried adding multiple shape files that are all zipped together but because together the files are too large to upload onto the map I have to resort to some other way to do this.

I have come across TOC coding for API and I have never used API before. I was wondering if there was a way to code the TOC or group layers into a web map or web application (without using a template) through the google chrome developer tool? I want to create my web app through the Web Application Builder if possible.

Does anyone know any way to use the developer tool kit on chrome to do this?

Answer (score 2):

With the new 4.0 JS API you can create groups:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/beta/api-reference/esri-layers-GroupLayer.html

The Web Scene Viewer in ArcGIS Online also supports groups but currently the 2D map viewer does not have this functionality yet.